# web page elements overlapping each other even when using percentage values in css

Tags: html, css

I have a page with structure like this. I want to divide the page into 6 sections so I have made 6 outer `div`s.

```
<body>
<div id="header">
  <img />
</div>
<div id="pageTitle">
title of page
</div>
<div id="section1" class="section">
  <div class="section-title">
  section 1
  </div>
  <form>
  <input />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="section">
  <div class="section-title">
  section 2
  </div>
  <form>
  <input />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="section">
  <div class="section-title">
  section 3
  </div>
  <form>
  <input />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="nav">
<a href="url" />
</div>
</body>
```

the problem is that when i try to zoom into the page by using `Ctrl++` in `firefox` or `chrome` the contents of the `div`s get overlapped on each other even when I am specifying all properties like `top`,`width`,`height`,`left` in percentages. now because percentages are relative units this should not happen.

```
#header {
position:absolute;
top:2%;
width:90%;
height:50%;
}

#pageTitle {
position:absolute;
top:30%;
left:20em;
}

.section {
margin:20px;
border:10px;
width:60%;
height:33%;
}

.section-title {
position:absolute;
font-size:1.4em;
left:70%;
margin:10px;
top:10%;
width:60%;
height:15%
}

#section1 {
position:absolute;
top:40%;
}

#section2 {
position:absolute;
top:70%;
}

#section3 {
position:absolute;
top:100%;
}

form {
position:absolute;
top:30%;
height:70%;
}

label {
display:block;
width:75%;
font-size:1em;
}

#nav {
position:absolute;
top:140%;
}
```

In some other page where I was using pixels instead of percentages the content didn't overlap on zooming into the page but pixels are absolute units. What's wrong?

Pixels are the dots on the screen so when I zoom in do pixels become bigger?

Comment: I think the overlapping is due to the fact that you are using Absolute positioning.

Comment: @Jeff: but on another page where i was using absolute positioning this problem didnt occur but on that page i was using pixels

Comment: Please can you supply valid markup? I'm struggling to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9Vzt/) that looks sensible as I don't know where the closing `<div>`s should be.

Comment: Here's a sensible (albeit) ugly jsFiddle representation. http://jsfiddle.net/3rWX7/

Comment: @lovesh It still looks very strange in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9Vzt/2/)

Comment: @Michael Mior: i havent seen jsFiddle before so cant make sense of it right now

Comment: jsFiddle simply gives you a way to quickly test HTML, JS, and CSS. I just copied your markup, added some colors and text, and fixed a small error.

Comment: Michael Mior: the blue background is the body or the section divs have collapsed?

Comment: @lovesh and I had a discussion on this in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1386/room-for-andyb-and-lovesh

Answer (score 1):

Its the box model.

Margin's extend past width and borders. It's easier to see when you're not using percents.

Say you have a div and it's CSS is:

```
.myDiv{margin:5px;width:100px;}
```

In reality on the page, your .myDiv is 110px wide and 110px high.

Since you're using absolute positioning, the browser is overlapping because it's putting things exactly where you told it to. Hopefully that makes sense.

I'd say get rid of the margin's and try using padding instead to control the spacing. If you're trying to do stuff with backgrounds, you might have to nest a child div in there and apply the background to that instead to get the same effect.

You can check out the [W3 School site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) for a quick and dirty overview.

Comment: the overlapping is still happening when i remove the margins but how can the margins be the problem here?

Comment: If you need more info on understanding the box model, I'm more than happy to help with that too.

Comment: Borders extend as well. Click that link about the box model so you can see what actually gets rendered on a page.

Comment: i am having some trouble positioning the elements though i understand absolute,relative,float,top,left,etc but sometimes i make changes and dey dont seem to take effect like sometimes setting height 50% doesnt make it look like 50% like for the header div above

Comment: Hmmm that ones a tad more difficult to explain. Each browser is a little weird about height still. Basically, HTML doesn't dictate what the height of something is unless it's wrapped in another item with a viable height associated with it. Basically it'll auto defer to it's content, not the browser if it's an outer element. If you're trying to do something that scales with screen size, you should look into jQuery - it'll be your most reliable option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this css code to fix that

```
section{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```