# is css worth learning in detail when most of the design can be done with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

whenever i try to do something in `CSS` that is not trivial people advice to use `JQuery`. So i am puzzled that is it worth going into the details of `CSS` or going into those drafts of `W3C` when everything can be done with `JQuery`?

Comment: You're using CSS (nearly) every time you're using a selector or applying a style in jQuery.

Comment: What on earth are you doing in CSS that is accomplished with jQuery, other than changing it dynamically?  You MUST know CSS.

Comment: CSS and jQuery are pretty different animals. While jQuery does use CSS to do some tasks, it is not equivalent. CSS is used to describe a general layout of the webpage (positioning, coloring, etc) while jQuery is used for many things which can including modifying the document to produce certain effects. jQuery can provide more interactive abilities that CSS can't, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't style your page with CSS first.

Comment: @Michael: can u help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666816/web-page-elements-overlapping-each-other-even-when-using-percentage-values-in-css). its been hours and i havent been able to figure out wats wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really style anything with jQuery. jQuery simply applies CSS styles, and makes it much easier to do so in some cases.

You still need a solid understanding of CSS in order to style using jQuery. "everything can be done with `JQuery`" is unfortunately not true. Also keep in mind users without JavaScript support.

Comment: :can u help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666816/web-page-elements-overlapping-each-other-even-when-using-percentage-values-in-css)

Comment: :can u guide me to a link or resource for understanding pixels and graphics basics cause i have trouble understanding things like what happens to pixels when u zoom in or zoom out

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any good resources. But to quickly answer, pixel size is a function of screen resolution and never changes. When you zoom in, the browser calculates a scaling factor and this will be multiplied onto any units specified using absolute values. So the effective size of a pixel changes, but the physical size will always remain fixed.

Comment: what if i am using relative values like percentage. does the browser still multiply by scaling factor?

Comment: In this case, the window will still have some absolute pixel size, which will be scaled up by the browser. The percentages will be based on the scaled value.

Comment: @lovesh - Please don't hijack the comments soliciting for help with your other questions. If your other question needs more eyes then edit more information into it to "bump" it or offer a bounty. What you're doing here is not good SO etiquette. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If somebody tells you that jQuery is an alternative to CSS, **disregard their opinion**. jQuery makes heavy use of CSS to do its magic. Learn both jQuery and CSS, and your knowledge of one will always compliment your use of the other.

Comment: :can u help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666816/web-page-elements-overlapping-each-other-even-when-using-percentage-values-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

Whoa there! The principles of seperation still stand to this day, that is

- CSS for styles
- HTML for meaning/semantics
- Javascript for client-side functionality

JQuery has not replaced anything, rather it gives you a more robust framework with which to manipulate the DOM. You absolutely need a fundamental understanding of those three before you can fully utilize what JQuery gives you.

Answer (score 2):

yes, absolutely... the more css you use, the faster your page will be, also, jquery isn't run until after the page is loaded, and jquery's style handling is almost exactly like css declarations

Comment: LoL always worried about overhead;)

Answer (score 2):

CSS is very important to learn. You don't want to rely on JavaScript to style anything if you can help it. CSS will render faster by default than JS will and if you get a JavaScript error then your site will suddenly not be styled...depending on how your code is organized.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest displaying content will be HTML content your server puts in the page that is styled with external CSS stylesheets.  You should generally only use jQuery for handling dynamic behavior (adding, removing, moving, responding to events, hiding, showing, querying servers, etc...).

Even when using jQuery, I find that code is most readable and maintainable and more accessible by web designers if I use jQuery to add/remove classes and all the actual styling is in a CSS stylesheet.

The best practice on the web will put most style information in cacheable CSS stylesheets, even if heavily using jQuery for dynamic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has nothing to do with CSS, CSS is one of the three fundamentals to web developement, the rest being HTML and JavaScript.

CSS, cascading style sheet is being used to style a webpage, while jquery, a supposed JS library is used to dynamically alter the changes in the webpage.

The three fundamental stacks are a must for every web developer.