# how to keep layout uniform across screen sizes

Tags: css, layout, position

which type of `positioning (absolute or relative)` and `units (percentage,em,px)` should be used to keep the elements at the same distance from each other even when the screen dimensions change or browser window is zommed in or out? when i create a page it and zoom in or out the elements sometimes overlap or the distance between them decreases. how can i want to prevent that? any other tips of generating a uniform layout are welcome.  here is link to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666816/web-page-elements-overlapping-each-other-even-when-using-percentage-values-in-css)

Comment: This is a great question as I, too, had trouble creating consistent web pages across browsers not too long ago. I now stay away from absolute positioning and use relative values and pixel positioning on my parent containers with percentage values on the components inside them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using strictly relative positioning and pixel amounts will prevent that. Try to think about all the elements on the page in relation to other elements, so that ultimately, everything is positioned relative to only one element on the page.

Comment: wat do u mean by pixel amounts. shoud i completely abandon absolute positioning

Comment: the `w3c` docs dont specify about the height and width property of relatively postioned elements like when u write `height:50%` and element is relatively positioned then wat would be the height?

Comment: ^ Height isn't technically supported for most elements. Lets put it this way, I usually shy away from absolute positioning and I try to define my parent containers using pixels. Then you can use percentages inside the containers.

Comment: so u mean i shud build an outermost absolute container for each page with pixel dimensions and then position all my elements inside relatively in percentages?

Comment: relative positioning means (at least I think citizen conn means that) that you use position:static instead of fixed, absolute or relative. Arange you block level elements by using margin, padding, and float instead of top, right, bottom, and left. If you need to center the whole page or position it in any other way use a single div around all other elements within the body and position this div. You can still use pixel values which is far easier than working with percent.

Comment: Pixels aren't really relative units since 100 pixels will always remain 100 pixels. You could argue that by saying that depending on your screen size and resolution, a pixel isn't always the same size, but that's about it. You could define everything using pixels by taking into account that not all users are going to be able to display everything if you cram components that are really wide on your page, but this way will solve the "elements overlapping" like you said earlier. Find the minimum pixel count you can use to be satisfied and use that so most people can display the whole content.

Comment: @Adam Smith: thanks for the answer i hav one more ques that how is width and height of a relatively positioned elemennt determined?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but it's pretty much the same as you would with a component that is not relative. You use a CSS and specify height: 100px; or height: 98%; or whatever. You should also use position: relative; in that block or toy around other options for position and see what works best for you.